# Identify users login type like Sign up or Sign In

Tags: bearer-token, azure-authentication, azure-ad-b2c, claims-authentication

We created Sign Up and Sign In userflow for our B2C application to authenticate users.

Everything is working fine. But I want to categorize signed in users and signed up users.

I checked the logs but there is no much difference. How to identify who are new users and who are existing users?

PS: Userflow is Sign Up and Sign In with username

EDIT: I am unable to get new flag in token claims even after adding application claim

Comment: You mean determin whether the user was logged in the first time using the Sign up flow or if it is an existing user that logged in using the sign-in flow?

Comment: Exactly I want whether the user selected sign up and logged in **or** entered their credentials and signed in directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a **User is new** (newUser) claim available within the Sign-up or sign-in policy that you can enable:

[image]

This will add the "newUser" flag to your token and it is true when the user sign up for the first time.